# `require` is not working

Tags: node.js, npm

Previously I was using Meteor 1.2, npm: '2.11.3' and node: '0.12.7' in my application and I was using

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
const remote = require('remote');
var fsPlus =remote.require('fs-plus');
var nconf = remote.require('nconf');
```

Currently I migrate it in Meteor 1.4 , npm: '2.15.9' and  node: '4.5.0' for above code

```
Error: Cannot find module 'path'
```

Comment: Did you try `npm rebuild`?

Comment: Does the error says `path` module not found? That can't be right

Comment: @abdulbarik: No i didn't try

Comment: @thefourtheye :yes error is showing `path` module not found

Comment: @sakshi Please check [this](https://asciinema.org/a/3gh310ksuhatcxieapo17ph4l)

Comment: @thefourtheye: I tried this and output is same:
$ node
> process.version
'v4.5.0'
> typeof require('path')
'object'
>

Comment: @abdulbarik: I tried the same but Error is same

Comment: @sakshi If it says `object`, it means that the module is loaded.

Comment: have you tried this npm install path